# Error detected by Parasoft

Tags: c, parasoft

I have a function in C, which contains lines below:

```
while (src=strstr(src,key)) {
        memmove(src,src+strlen(key),1+strlen(src+strlen(key)));
    }
```

When I run parasoft to check the function, I receive so many errors from these lines:

```
Not enclosed with brackets assignment was found in 'while' condition expression
LHS operand of '+' operator is 'unsigned long'
LHS operand of '+' operator is 'unsigned long'
LHS operand of '+' operator is 'unsigned long'
RHS operand of '+' operator is 'unsigned long'
RHS operand of '+' operator is 'unsigned long'
RHS operand of '+' operator is 'unsigned long'
Third param to 'memmove' function depends on second: src, key
```

Do you have any idea where theses errors come from?

Comment: Take the expression `src+strlen(key)` for example, the left-hand side of the addition is (I'm *guessing*) of type `char *` while the right-hand side is of type `size_t` (often a type-alias of e.g. `unsigned long`). This is a valid expression and so you could consider messages for that as false positives.

Comment: The first "error" you could get rid of by doing e.g. `while ((str = strstr(src, key)) != NULL)`.

Comment: What is the declaration of `src`? `char*` as assumed by Joachim?

Comment: The last warning: wtf?!

Answer (score 1):

The first message is because the tool suspects you could have meant:

```
while (src == strstr(src, key)) {  /* comparison instead of assignment */
```

To make clear the assignment is intended, some tools expect you to write

```
while ((src = strstr(src, key))) {
```